# What's faster to access: wide or deep folder structures?

Tags: performance, directory, directory-structure

Let's say I have a project that's likely to require the creation of several folders. What takes less time to access, a wide structure or a deep structure?

Wide:

```
tests
|
+-- 2016-08-08
|    |
|    +-- test 1
|    |   |
|    |   +-- sub-test 1
|    |   |
|    |   +-- sub-test 2
|    |   |
|    |   ...
|    |   
|    +-- test 2
|    |  |
|    |  +-- sub-test 1
|    |  |
|    |  +-- sub-test 2
|    |  |
|    |  ...
|    ...   
|    
+-- 2016-08-09
|   |
|   +-- test 1
|   |   |
|   |   +-- sub-test 1
|   |   |
|   |   +-- sub-test 2
|   |   |
|   |   ...
|   |   
|   +-- test 2
|   |  |
|   |  +-- sub-test 1
|   |  |
|   |  +-- sub-test 2
|   |  |
|   |  ...
|   ...   
...
```

Wide:

```
tests
|
+-- test_1
|   |
|   +-- sub-test 1
|   |   |
|   |   +-- 2016-08-08
|   |   |
|   |   +-- 2016-08-09
|   |   |
|   |   ...
|   |
|   +-- sub-test 2
|   |   |
|   |   +-- 2016-08-08
|   |   |
|   |   +-- 2016-08-09
|   |   |
|   |   ...
|   ...
|
+-- test_2
|   |
|   +-- sub-test 1
|   |   |
|   |   +-- 2016-08-08
|   |   |
|   |   +-- 2016-08-09
|   |   |
|   |   ...
|   |
|   +-- sub-test 2
|   |   |
|   |   +-- 2016-08-08
|   |   |
|   |   +-- 2016-08-09
|   |   |
|   |   ...
|   ...
...
```

In the above example the assumption is the number of date folders is greater than the test folders.

My question pertains to a developer (i.e. *a human*) accessing the files, not a machine (although I'm curious if there's a difference there too). References to quantitative studies would also be great.